# Max DB size in SQL Server 2000 MSDE

Tags: sql-server

We are currently evaluation our hosting options and the cheapest suitable option we've found only has SQL Server 2000 MSDE as the db server.

What is the max size of a db on the server?  Is there a max total size for dbs combined?

Comment: What hosting have you looked at? Have you looked at discountasp.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2GB :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165672(SQL.90).aspx

Answer (score 1):

2Gb.

Search for MSDE on this page:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933149.aspx